# Trying to install Ubuntu - Install menu loops back to install menu regardless of option chosen

Tags: system-installation, windows

Morning,

Very new to this so please be gentle :-)

Trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 via USB onto Windows XP machine, but cannot get past install menu option. Regardless on what option I choose (Install Ubuntu, Try Ubuntu without Install etc), the screen goes back to the BIOS page and then back to the install menu?

Originally tried pendrivelinux.com, then UNetbootin to create USB but same problem exists.

OS Name Microsoft Windows XP Professional

Version 5.1.2600 Service Pack 3 Build 2600

OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation

System Manufacturer Dell Inc

System Model    XPS 630i

System Type X86-based PC

Processor   x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 11 GenuineIntel ~2400 Mhz

BIOS Version/Date   Dell Inc. 1.0.5, 17/04/2008

SMBIOS Version  2.5

Windows Directory   C:\WINDOWS

System Directory    C:\WINDOWS\system32

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)